# Solr Dismax qp - How to use mm with TF/IDF ranking

Tags: solr

Solr's dismax query parser allows me to specify a minimum number (mm) of clauses to match, however I would like this to take the IDF of the clause into account. For example

Lets say I have a mm = 66% and I search for "BMW 330i car" I would like solr to return a document with a title of "BMW 330i" but not a document with a title of "BMW car" on the basis that "car" has a much lower IDF than "330i"

Is it possible to tell Solr to take the TF/IDF info account when calculating the mm clauses?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.  You'd need to build that strategy yourself.  Look at [CustomScoreQuery](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/03/12/using-customscorequery-for-custom-solrlucene-scoring/) first, as a potential solution.